Wiring a Lutron toggler dimmer
Wanted to switch existing light switch to a Lutron toggle dimmer switch.
I have 5 wires coming from the wall
2 red, 2 white and 1 ground green
The toggle only has three spots plus a ground. What do I do with the extra wire?


Please show pictures, especially of how it was wired in the first place.

The only way this makes sense is if this is the middle 4-way switch of a 3-way/4-way/3-way switch setup. Are there two other switches that also turn the lights on/off? Are there black wires in the back of the box connected together with a wire nut?

Correct,  there are 2 other switches. Yes there are 2 black wires in the back connected together.

Is replacing the other two switches an option?

From the pictures, this looks like a four-way switch. You probably have a three-way dimmer, and I don't think a four-way dimmer exists. If your heart is set on a dimmer in this location, I would get a Pico switch. Wire the dimmer on one side of the three-way, then add the remote switch in that four-way slot. Wire nut the two reds and two whites together and call it good.
